# Sniffing configured http header in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk

I'm making an biztalk application that uses a HTTP adapter and a dynamic send port, and I'm trying to configure the send port in an orchestration but after the configurations I can't see the tag AUTHORIZATION in http header using wireshark.

Some code in orchestration:

```
PrtGenericIssuer(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address) = wsUri;
PrtGenericIssuer(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType) = "HTTP";
reqIssuerGetAccounts(HTTP.UseSSO) = false;
reqIssuerGetAccounts(HTTP.AuthenticationScheme) = "Basic";
reqIssuerGetAccounts(HTTP.Username) = wsUsr;
reqIssuerGetAccounts(HTTP.Password) = wsPwd;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i'm reading the iis logFile and i can't see the response 401. I know everytime i make a request, i receive a response with 401, and only after that i can send the authentication, so if i never receive the 401 response, i will never see the credentials. How can i configure the iis for require authentication? i think this is the problem

Comment: Basic authentication does not require a double round trip. The 401 you are expecting is when you use "NTLM" authentication. This will execute without credentials on the first request, get a challenge from the server and then the client is suppose to send the correct authentication response to that challenge. You are using "Basic" authentication which are "username/password" HTTP headers.